# PHP - Using preg_replace with file_get_contents

Tags: php, preg-replace, file-get-contents

The above code is working ok:

```
<?php

function clearPage($content, $class) {
$arr = array(
            '@^(.*?)<div class="'.$class.'">(.*?)</div>(.*?)$@i' => '<div class="'.$class.'">$2</div>'
            );

    return preg_replace(array_keys($arr), array_values($arr), $content);


}


$class = "something";
$content = "31xu1823y8<div class="something">Wanted</div>912u38u3"
$result = clearPage($content, $class);
echo $result;
?>
```

This outputs:

```
<div class="something">Wanted</div>
```

But I want to make the variable content, be the html code from a website page. So I change the last code to something like:

```
$class = "something";
$content = file_get_contents('index.php');
$result = clearPage($content, $class);
echo $result;

This outputs all the webpage! Why!?
```

Comment: I'm guessing you'll find an answer in this SO question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: And yes, if you read from `input.php`, you'll not get rendered HTML, but PHP source with only HTML snippets. (Regex problem: DOTALL flag.)

Answer (score 0):

Using regex or string matching is the worst way to parse HTML.

You need to use the DOM:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

or a 3rd party dom library like so:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Why not closevote to one of the hundreds of similar questions with likewise unspecific answers?

Comment: I think my solution is ok, but the problem, I think is that I am not getting the html code from the page, so it doesn't replace anything.